# Flutter: Column Row [Beginner]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new into Flutter and at the moement I try to code my first App. 
I just want to implement a screen with Text Fields - that worked.
Now I want to arrange the first two text field next to each other. I tried to use Row () and I got no errors, but suddenly the emulator shows me just a blank page.

Could someone tell me what I have to change? I don't know what I did wrong, because I do not get any errors.

Thanks for help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestEditState createState() => _TestEditState();
}

class _TestEditState extends State<TestEdit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        //`true` if you want Flutter to automatically add Back Button when needed,
        //or `false` if you want to force your own back button every where
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
            children: <Widget>[
              //Row(children:[

              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'InputFirst',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'InputSecond',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //],
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap texxtfiled inside the row with expanded widget

Answer (score 2):

`TextField` widget will try to horizontally expand as much as possible.

So if you want to put an `TextField` in a `Row`, you should wrap it with `Flexible`(or `Expanded`) widget.

Try this,

```
class TestEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestEditState createState() => _TestEditState();
}

class _TestEditState extends State<TestEdit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        //`true` if you want Flutter to automatically add Back Button when needed,
        //or `false` if you want to force your own back button every where
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
            children: <Widget>[
              //Row(children:[

              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              Expanded( //TODO: Wrap with `Expanded` 
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'InputFirst',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded( //TODO: Wrap with Expanded
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                  child: TextField(
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'InputSecond',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //],
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: false,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Input',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you need add widgets vertically you need to add column and in horizontal way you need to add row. Both widgets contain children.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Beginner extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeginnerState createState() => _BeginnerState();
}

class _BeginnerState extends State<Beginner> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('A'),
              Text('B'),
              Text('C'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('A'),
              Text('B'),
              Text('C'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('A'),
              Text('B'),
              Text('C'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Text('A'),
              Text('B'),
              Text('C'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```